# How to make, groupe and transform this response?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have groups and users with relationship Group -> hasMany -> Users
user have field status with values (premium, gold, platinum)

How get all groups with count of users and their statuses with count?

For example:

```
[Group1 (30) => [ premium (5), gold (10), platinum (25)]]

[Group2 (21) => [ premium (1), gold (15), platinum (5)]]

[Group3 (15) => [ premium (3), gold (10), platinum (2)]]
```

Group fields (id, name)
User fields (id, name, status)

Comment: show table structure and what u have implemented till now

Comment: first post updated

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: omg and what does it means?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

select group_concat(concat(status,':',c)), sum(c) from (select Group,status,count(status) as c from **You table** group by status,Group) as L group by Group;